# How to show full ruler lines in the Chrome inspector?

Tags: html, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

The ruler from inspector in Firefox looks like this. It shows wide lines around box. [lines in Firefox](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n3Lsc.jpg)

But Chrome inspector has them only on left and top. Lines don't continue from bottom and right sides. [take a look at my red lines](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fHGPP.jpg)

Is it possible to have all lines like in Firefox ?

Comment: use this tool, and click on enable element mode on the toolbar at the top left https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/page-ruler/jlpkojjdgbllmedoapgfodplfhcbnbpn?hl=en

Comment: I saw, unfortunately, this tool is not usable together with inspector (

Answer (score 3):

I use chrome extensions, these two are pretty good: [Page Ruler](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/page-ruler/emliamioobfffbgcfdchabfibonehkme/related?hl=en) and [Grid Ruler](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/grid-ruler/joadogiaiabhmggdifljlpkclnpfncmj/related?hl=en)